# Date format changes when userform text box sends a required date format to sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a **userform** from where I send a date in **mm/yy (Month/Year)** format to the worksheet. When transferred to the sheet, it changes format and in another location of the sheet it is displaying very different.

For date format, I'm using the following code:

```
TextBox3.SetFocus

If IsDate(TextBox3.Text) Then
Debug.Print Format(CDate(TextBox3.Text), "mm/yy")
 Else
Debug.Print "Not a valid date"
End If
```

Transferring Code:

```
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Worksheet
Set Y = Sheets2
X = Y.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
with Y
.Cells(X + 1, "D").Value = TextBox3.Value
End with
```

When I transfer date from userform it shows like this:

[image]

The same dates are showing differently in the sheet:

[image]

I want to display the date in the format **Month** and **Year**. For example, if a date is **June-2021** then show as **06/21**.

Comment: `Format(cDate, "mmm-yyyy")`

Comment: its not working

Comment: You just need to format the cells on the worksheet to show how you wish. Note that `23-Jul` and `29-Aug` will be interpreted as being of this year.  If the `23` and `29` represent a year, and not a day, you will need to process things differently.

Comment: I made changes in Cells but the issue is still there

Comment: Yes, **23** and **29** are the years, not days. I want it as **23-Jul** to **07/23** and **29-Aug** to **08/29**.

Comment: Will the month always be `mmm` and never `m` or `mm`?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell where you need help since the code you provided just prints the date in the immediate window. In general, you need to make formatting changes to the cell itself. So after you set the data from the form, do something like this to your worksheet.

Range("A2:A50").NumberFormat = "mm/yy"

Edit: To update the code above

```
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Worksheet
Set Y = Sheets2
X = Y.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
with Y
.Cells(X + 1, "D").Value = TextBox3.Value
.Cells(X + 1, "D").NumberFormat = "mm/yy"
End with
```

Comment: Thank. I have posted a transferring code. Could you please check again?

Comment: You can update the code to modify the format of the target cell. After .Cells(X + 1, "D").Value = TextBox3.Value put in .Cells(X + 1, "D").NumberFormat = "mm/yy"

Comment: I am getting Yellow line error on .Cells(X + 1, "D").NumberFormat = "mm/yy"